# matplotlib plot sampling strategy at a 3H frequency

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

## Problem Overview

I am trying to plot a sampling schedule for an experiment I ran. We set out to sample every 3 hours, and I want to be able to observe the time at which each sample was plotted on a daily cycle.

- The x-axis variable should be time of day (00:00 - 23:00).
- Each row (or maybe y-axis variable?) should be a new day.
- The point should be coloured by whether it was released EARLY (blue) or LATE (red) compared with the ideal 3-hourly sampling strategy.

I am envisioning the plot to look something like the below:

[image: Expected Plot Output]

## Simulate dummy data to explain the problem

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import itertools

value = np.random.normal(size=100)
expected_time = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", freq="180min", periods=100)
# add random offset to simulate being +/- the true expected release time
time_deltas = np.array([DateOffset(minute=max(0, min(int(i), 59))) for i in np.abs(np.random.normal(0, 10, size=100))])
time = [expected_time[i] + time_deltas[i] if (i % 2 == 0) else expected_time[i] - time_deltas[i] for i in range(100)]

df = pd.DataFrame({"launchtime": time, "value": value})
ds = df.set_index("launchtime").to_xarray()
ds = ds.assign_coords(expected_time=("launchtime", expected_time))
```

As you can see the underlying data has an observation roughly every 3 hours (although the exact time slightly varies).

```py
In []: ds["launchtime.hour"]

Out[]:
<xarray.DataArray 'hour' (launchtime: 100)>
array([ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21,  0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21,  0,
        3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21,  0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21,  0,  3,
        6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21,  0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21,  0,  3,  6,
        9, 12, 15, 18, 21,  0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21,  0,  3,  6,  9,
       12, 15, 18, 21,  0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21,  0,  3,  6,  9, 12,
       15, 18, 21,  0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21,  0,  3,  6,  9])
Coordinates:
  * launchtime     (launchtime) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 ... 2000-01-13T09:0...
    expected_time  (launchtime) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 ... 2000-01-13T09:0...
```

## Initial attempt using `matplotlib`

```py
# get the total number of days
day_months = list(itertools.product(np.unique(ds["launchtime.day"].values), np.unique(ds["launchtime.month"].values)))
N_DAYS = len(day_months)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(N_DAYS, 1, figsize=(6, 0.5*N_DAYS), sharey=True)
for ix, (day, month) in enumerate(day_months):
    
    mask = (ds["launchtime.day"] == day) & (ds["launchtime.month"] == month)
    day = ds.sel(launchtime=mask)
    error = np.array([pd.to_datetime(dt) for dt in day.launchtime.values]) - np.array([pd.to_datetime(dt) for dt in day.expected_time.values])
    error = [e.total_seconds() for e in error]
    colors = ["r" if e > 0 else "b" if e < 0 else "grey" for e in error]
    print(colors)
    ax = axs[ix]

    ax.scatter(day.expected_time, [1 for _ in range(len(day.expected_time))], color=colors)
    ax.set_ylabel(f"Day {ix}")
    
    # remove the spines and ytick labels
    for spine in ax.spines:
        ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)

    ax.axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)

plt.xticks(rotation=60)
fig.suptitle("Radiosonde Releases over a month campaign")
```

[image: Current Code Output]

# Remaining Problems

The main problems I am seeing are:

1. The x-axis should be the daily cycle, not the "datetime" which also includes the Day/Month/Year
2. It would be nice to neatly stack each day as a new column, either as a facet, or using each day as the y-axis variable

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete and reproducible example with the following key features:

- the data is processed exclusively with pandas using vectorized operations;
- the simulation of the time deltas is corrected by replacing DateOffset with Timedelta objects, so about half the points are now blue;
- the approach of stacking subplots is preserved (rather than displaying days with a y-axis variable) as this avoids extra computations for the x-axis values and makes it easier to draw grey lines (as shown in the example image) by using the x-axis tick marks and spine;
- the problem of aligning the x-axes (e.g. last subplot) is solved by setting appropriate x-axis limits using timestamps for each day that are not taken from the list of `expected_time` timestamps in case the frequency is sometimes irregular (e.g. no launch at midnight on one day);
- `fig.subplots_adjust` and the figure height are used to adjust the vertical space between the subplots to ensure that the tick labels are visible, instead of using `tight_layout` or `constrained_layout` that modify the figure size.

**Import packages and generate sample data**

```py
import numpy as np               # v 1.19.2
import pandas as pd              # v 1.2.3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # v 3.3.4

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=1)  # random number generator
size = 30
expected_time = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", freq="180min", periods=size)
time_deltas = np.array([pd.Timedelta(int(i), unit="minute")
                        for i in abs(rng.normal(0, 10, size=size))])
time = [expected_time[i] + time_deltas[i] if (i % 2 == 0)
        else expected_time[i] - time_deltas[i] for i in range(size)]
df = pd.DataFrame({"launchtime": time, "expected_time": expected_time})
```

**Create matplotlib figure**

```py
# Create day/month tuples based on expected time to ensure correct plotting for
# cases where a day would have only one launch time occuring early before midnight
day_months = [(dt.day, dt.month) for dt in df["expected_time"].dt.date.unique()]
N_DAYS = len(day_months)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(N_DAYS, 1, figsize=(6, 1*N_DAYS), sharey=True)
for ix, (day, month) in enumerate(day_months):
    day = df[(df["expected_time"].dt.day==day) & (df["expected_time"].dt.month==month)]
    deltas = pd.to_datetime(day["expected_time"]) - pd.to_datetime(day["launchtime"])
    error = deltas.dt.total_seconds()
    colors = ["red" if e > 0 else "blue" if e < 0 else "grey" for e in error]
    # Create midnight timestamp regardless of the times of the data points
    ts = pd.to_datetime(day["expected_time"].dt.date.min())
    
    # Create subplot with appropriate x-axis limits and ticks
    ax = axs[ix]
    ax.scatter(day["launchtime"], np.repeat(1, len(day)), color=colors, clip_on=False)
    ax.set_xlim(ts, ts + pd.Timedelta(23, unit="hour"))
    ax.set_xticks(day["expected_time"])
    ax.set_xticklabels(day["expected_time"].dt.strftime("%H:%S"))
#     ax.set_xticklabels(day["expected_time"].dt.hour)  # alternative method
    ax.set_ylabel(f"Day {ix}", labelpad=25, y=0.3, size=12)
    ax.set_yticks([])
    
    # Format spines and ticks to draw grey lines
    for spine in ["left", "right", "top"]:
        ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["bottom"].set(linewidth=3, color="lightgrey")
    ax.tick_params(axis="x", direction="in", length=13,
                   width=3, color="lightgrey", pad=7)

fig.suptitle("Radiosonde Releases over a month campaign", size=14, y=0.95)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
```

[image: plot]